# Wordpress and Sessions, picking up only Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have Wordpress website where I setup my own table to store users login credentials. People can register fine but when it comes time to login and create a session it doesn't seem to work.

This is in my header:

```
<?php
// Initialize session
session_start();
// Initialize DB
include("functions/connect.php");
<span class="login">
      <?php  
        if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['Username']))  
        { 
      ?>
        <p>Welcome, <?php echo $_SESSION['Username']?></p>
      <?php 
        }
        else
        {
      ?>
        <p>Login</p><p>|</p><p>Signup</p>
      <?php } ?>
</span>
```

This is on my login page.

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name']) AND isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password']) AND isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name'])){
                $username = mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']);
                $password = mysql_escape_string(md5($_POST['password']));

                $search = mysql_query("SELECT username, password, active FROM wp_thread_users WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."' AND active='1'") or die(mysql_error()); 
                $match  = mysql_num_rows($search);

                if($match > 0){
                    $msg = 'Login Complete! Thanks';
                    //$email = $row['EmailAddress'];  
                    $_SESSION['Username'] = $username;  
                    //$_SESSION['EmailAddress'] = $email;  
                    $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;  
                }else{
                    $msg = 'Login Failed!<br /> Please make sure that you enter the correct details and that you have activated your account.';
                }
            }


        ?>
        <!-- stop PHP Code -->

        <!-- title and description -->  
        <h2>Login Form</h2>
        <p>Please enter your name and password to login</p>

        <?php 
            if(isset($msg)){ // Check if $msg is not empty
                echo '<div class="statusmsg">'.$msg.'</div>'; // Display our message and add a div around it with the class statusmsg
            } ?>

        <!-- start sign up form --> 
        <form action="" method="post">
            <label for="name">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" value="" />

            <input type="submit" class="submit_button" value="login" />
        </form>
```

My code works on a regular php page without Wordpress, but as soon as I login on the Wordpress site it redirects me to "wp-login.php" also it never stores the session. Any help?

EDIT:

Forgot to add that this is in my functions.php

```
add_action('init', 'initEverything');

function initEverything() {
    if(!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's really annoying when people ask questions like this rather than help, but why aren't you just using WordPress's wp_users table? Then you can just log someone in with one line function `wp_signon`:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon

You might be creating extra work for yourself by not using WordPress's out-of-the-box user management stuff.

**EDIT:** Given our comments below, here's some pointers on simple ways to do what you're trying to do using WordPress's `wp_users`. I've done exactly what you're trying to achieve on other sites and I'd highly recommend not creating a custom user table.

**Custom user meta:** http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta

**Prevent users accessing wp-admin (one of many many simple ways of doing this):** http://pento.net/2011/06/19/preventing-users-from-accessing-wp-admin/

I'm actually writing a blog post on how to do this at the moment so I'll let you know once it's up.

Comment: I tried to go about using that but I don't want users to have Wordpress backend access as well as I will be taking in different fields rather then the default ones Wordpress provides. I only want admins to have Wordpress access and users to have a dashboard that I create.

Comment: I've built a few sites like this and I would really recommend you do use WordPress's user management. It's pretty easy to stop WP users seeing the back end, there are plugins/simple manual methods to prevent access. It's also very easy to add custom meta fields for users: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta

Comment: Interesting thanks, that blog post you are working on will definitely be helpful to me as I searched everywhere for the best way to do it and could not find anything but plugins which I did not want to use. The blocking of the backend works great [just tested it]. The thing I still can't find is how to customize wordpress's register to my liking.

Comment: Hi shayward - I've now responded below with the blog post, at last!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is now ridiculously out of date but I've finally created a how-to for doing what it is I think you're trying to do. There are a few bits I can flesh out like adding user meta but I'd love your feedback and to know if it helps you:

http://haveposts.com/2013/01/how-to-create-a-really-simple-custom-wordpress-login-and-sign-up-without-plugins/

It's the inaugural post to the blog so any other thoughts you have are welcome.

Cheers,

Jack